# Сократить повторяющиеся дубликаты массива

Tags: php

Как сократить повторяющиеся подряд элементы массива?
Например :
Из 6,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,8,1,1,1,6
Получить 6,1,2,3,4,8,1,6

Comment: Справочник читаем по функциям http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Как у вас получилось до сих пор?

Comment: @Taypfoon сперва `array_slice()` потом `array_unique()`. Или наоборот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может костыльно, но вот

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if (isset($array[$key-1])) {
       if (($array[$key-1])!=$value) {
        $result[]=$value;   
        }
    } else {
    $result[]=$value;
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a42b5adfd1ee8a647f64c62cf386a7a2b9f30533)

Comment: Не скромничайте, ответ не костыльный, а лучший. И действующий.

Answer (score 0):

Функция [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)

```
$arr = array('6', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '8');
$result = array_unique($arr);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо , но это немного не то, эта функция мне известна. Дописал значений чтобы было понятно чего я хочу. array_unique удалит повторяющиеся значения массива а мне надо сократить.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php):

**php>=5.6:**

```
$a = [6,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,8,1,1,1,6];
$b = array_filter($a, function($i) use ($a) {
  return $i === 0 || $a[$i-1] !== $a[$i];
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

echo implode(',', $b); // 6,1,2,3,4,8,1,6
```

**php<5.6:**

```
$a = [6,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,8,1,1,1,6];
$filtered_keys = array_filter(array_keys($a), function($i) use ($a) {
  return $i === 0 || $a[$i-1] !== $a[$i];
});
$b = array_map(function($i) use ($a) {
  return $a[$i];
}, $filtered_keys);

echo implode(',', $b); // 6,1,2,3,4,8,1,6
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Jf0LYQJ.png

Comment: @Taypfoon, флаг доступен с php>=5.6